# having problems with this 1:1 association in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems with this simple association (one to one association: Each with have just one role); I can't really see the problem:
Thanks for your time!

This is my schema:

```
 create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "description"
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.string  "email"
    t.string  "password_digest"
    t.integer "tel"
  end
```

And my models:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role
end
```

This is my error I'm getting:

```
 :001 > u = User.first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "fer", email: nil, password_digest: nil, tel: nil>
 :002 > r = Role.first
  Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles"   ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Role id: 1, description: nil, name: "simple_user", user_id: nil>
 :003 > u.role << r
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE "roles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):3
```

Comment: What is the problem?  You've not described it at all.

Comment: "I can't really see the problem" - neither can we. :)

Comment: sorry about that guys I'll edit my entry now!

Comment: `#<Role id: 1, description: nil, name: "simple_user", user_id: nil>` looks like your role wasn't created correctly as it doesn't have a reference to the user to which it should be associated.  It might also help to add a non null validation to your `:user` attribute in `Role` assuming a `Role` must always have an associated `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a has_one, you can't do `<<`, you'll do an `=`.  Doing this will be a database update (setting primary and foreign keys and saving)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm just guessing at what your problem is since you didn't really explain what problem you're running into, but it looks like you didn't define foreign keys in your schema, so you're database doesn't know how to do the look ups on your association.  I would rewrite your migration like so:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string  "name"
  t.string  "email"
  t.string  "password_digest"
  t.integer "tel"
end

create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
  t.string  "description"
  t.string  "name"
  t.references :user
end

execute <<-SQL
  ALTER TABLE roles
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_roles_users
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users(id)
SQL
```

Comment: That is, assuming you're using a SQL based storage solution.

Comment: sorry mate I'll edit my entry! but I wanna try what you suggest! let you know soon!

Comment: this is my reference in Roles-table: "t.integer user_id" is it not good enough? It should the same like "t.references :user"

Comment: It should be the same, I'm just a proponent of using symbols vs strings and using `t.references` so that when I come back to this code in a week/month/year it's immediately obvious what I was trying to do.